# Is there any possibility of a python discord bot posting in a specific channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm using Python to make a Bot for our Discord-Server.
I want the bot to post something into a specific Channel everytime it is restarting.

My Code

```
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
   msg = 'Ready when you are :thumbsup:'
   await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

I think I have to change the

```
message.channel
```

but i dunno how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `on_ready` event does not have the `message` object. You'll have to iterate over all the channels that the bot has access to and post in the one that you want. Below is an example, where the bot will first iterate over [`client.servers`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.servers), then over [`server.channels`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.channels) and then send `msg` to each [`channel.name`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel.name) that is "general".

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    msg = 'Ready when you are :thumbsup:'
    for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            if channel.name == 'general':
                await client.send_message(channel, msg)
```